# Dialog does not get dismissed on call

Tags: java, android, dialog

```
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
                    {       
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        longOperations();
                    }
                });
```

In the above code , whenever I do dialog.dismiss(), the dialog is not getting dismissed on the spot, rather, android wait for the below method finish. why ? As I want to the dialog get dismissed whenever I call it.

Comment: can you try like this... set OnDismissListener for Dialog and do longOperation() in that listener...

Comment: @GopalRao thanks. works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your `longOperations()` are happening on the UI thread. The dialog is not dismissed until after the onClick code is finished executing. You should move this into an AsyncTask.

Comment: @tony9099 even you use OnDismissListener, it's not recommended to do long running task in UI thread... consider using AsyncTask or write your own Thread by extending Thread...

Comment: Yes, but putting it in onDismissListener will still cause the operations to execute on the UI thread. Depending on how long those operations are, it can still noticeably freeze up your UI.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz, true, I'll shift to asynctask.